# Why the type of Mat become int even I initialize it with double in OpenCV and parameter by reference don't work?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a matrix which initialized to be a double type. However whenever I modify the type, the value it stored always become int. It's so strange that I don't know the reason. The code is very simple works as follows:

```
void func(Mat &mat) {
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        mat.data[i] = (double)i/2;
        printf("data: %f\n", (double)i/2);
        printf("mat: %f\n", (double)mat.data[i]);
    }
}

int main() {
    Mat test(1,1,CV_64FC(10), Scalar(0));
    func(test);
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        cout << "final value: " << (double)test.data[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

the data could be 0.5, 1.5, 2.5 and so on. However when I fetch the value from test,it only have 0,1,2 and 3. I don't know why it cannot store the double value even I use CV_64F.
Also it is very strange that in the main function, the test mat didn't change its value. I have pass the parameter by reference but why it didn't work?

Comment: please use mat.at<double>(r,c) to access it, not the rad data pointer.

Comment: You'd better use `Mat test(1, 10, CV_64FC1, Scalar(0));` and `mat.at<double>(0, i)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In OpenCV's core.hpp, there is this code

```
class CV_EXPORTS Mat
{
public:
    ...
    //! pointer to the data
    uchar* data;
    ...
};
```

That means that regardless of what type of data is stored in a Mat, the data pointer is always a `uchar*`. Therefore the following line is wrong.

```
    mat.data[i] = (double)i/2;
```

If `i = 5`, then `(double)i/2 = 2.5`. The assignment to `mat.data[i]` implicitly casts `2.5` to an unsigned char, so the fraction part is discarded and `2` actually gets stored.
You could try

```
  ((double*)mat.data)[i] = (double)i/2;
  ...
  printf("mat: %f\n", ((double*)mat.data)[i]);
```

But that is pretty ugly, and code that directly accesses the data pointer usually has a bad smell.
A neater solution would be

```
double* p = mat.ptr<double>(0);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
    p[i] = (double) i / 2;

    printf("data: %f\n", (double) i / 2);
    printf("mat:  %f\n", p[i]);
}
```

---

Regarding the second part of your question, because a Mat is essentially a smart pointer, and you are not reallocating data in `func()`, it does not matter whether you pass the Mat by reference. Things will work just as well if you have:

```
void func(Mat mat) { ...
```

However, in main() the following line is wrong, as it is indexing the doubles as bytes

```
    cout << "final value: " << (double)test.data[i] << endl;
```

Change it to the following and you will get the correct results.

```
    cout << "final value: " << ((double*)test.data)[i] << endl;
```

There are, of course, many other possible ways of doing that, including:

```
    cout << "final value: " << test.at<Vec<double, 10> >(0, 0)[i] << endl;
```